# Error handling on a query not working in controller laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to simple error handling whereby if  a query doesn't return anything I want to redirect the user to a 404 page, but for now I just echoing a message to see if it triggers, here is my code

```
public function show($user_id, $username) {

    $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->where('name', $username)->get();

    if (count($user = 0)) {
        echo "REEEEEEE";
    }
    else 
    {
        $user->load('comments.users', 'posts.users');

        return $user;
    }
    //return view ('users.show', compact('user'));

}
```

This only echos the message and doesn't load the relationships or return the user if the query returns something, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
$userCount = User::where('id', $user_id)->where('name', $username)->count();

if ($userCount == 0)
```

In your code you have a wrong if statement:

`if (count($user = 0))` becomes `if (count(0))`

Comment: It works nice one boss, any idea why my code doesn't work? Incorrect syntax?

Comment: @user6073700 you mistyped, `count($user = 0)` is not a correct statement.  You assign user to 0 and then `if (count(0))`. If it helped mark my answer as right, thanks